# Table creation error due to Decimal datatype

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am Trying to Create this Table and it gives Error "fractional digit must be 0 and total digit number"

```
Create Table DBL2.WorkOrderRouting
(
WorkOrderID int,
ProductID  Varchar(10),
OperationSequence int,
LocationID Varchar(10),
ScheduledStartDate Date,
ScheduledEndDate Date,
ActualStartDate Date,
ActualEndDate Date,
ActualResourceHrs Decimal (1,2),
PlannedCost Decimal (2,2),
ActualCost Decimal (2,5)
) Primary Index (WorkOrderID,ProductID,OperationSequence);
```

Decimal seems fine , I am not getting it. Where is the problem!

Comment: `decimal(overall_digits, fractional_digits)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `DECIMAL` on another way. The first value needs to be higher than the second value:

```
Create Table DBL2.WorkOrderRouting
(
    WorkOrderID int,
    ProductID  Varchar(10),
    OperationSequence int,
    LocationID Varchar(10),
    ScheduledStartDate Date,
    ScheduledEndDate Date,
    ActualStartDate Date,
    ActualEndDate Date,
    ActualResourceHrs Decimal (3,2),
    PlannedCost Decimal (4,2),
    ActualCost Decimal (7,5)
) Primary Index (WorkOrderID,ProductID,OperationSequence);
```

---

You can find the following example [on the documentation](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1143-160K/tgm1472241376275.html):

> Consider the number 256.78. Its type is DECIMAL (5,2)